# A Convention of Set Builder Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the set $$ X = \{\{a,b\} : a \in \mathbb N ~\wedge~ b \in\{0,1\} \},$$
would the set $\{1\}$ be contained in $X$? I'm not sure how to interpret what happens when $a$ takes on the value $1$ in the set-builder notation. Do we discard $\{1,1\}$ or place it in the set as $\{1\}$?

Comment: You place it in the set as $\{1\}$ ([look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) at describing sets).

Comment: $\{ 1, 1 \}$ ***is*** $\{1 \}$; they are the *same* set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a=b=1$ you have $\{a,b\}=\{1,1\}=\{1\}$, hence $\{1\}\in X$.
Recall
$$\{a,b\}=\{z:z=a\vee z=b\}$$
thus
\begin{align}
\{a,a\}
&=\{z:z=a\vee z=a\}\\
&=\{z:z=a\}\\
&=\{a\}
\end{align}
Equivalently, you have $\{a,b\}=\{a\}\cup\{b\}$ so that
\begin{align*}
\{a,a\}
&=\{a\}\cup\{a\}\\
&=\{a\}
\end{align*}

Comment: Switch $\vee$ and $\wedge$ I think.  Even better, since these are confusing to you (and to others), use "and" and "or" in there.

Comment: Thank you, a nice way of thinking about it :)